# Why do my objects get placed and sized so perfectly when I add them to a UIKitView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

So I have the following UIKit elements I am adding to my UIViewController to control the simulation that appears. I expected to have to write a lot of placement code but instead everything appears perfectly no-mater what device... my question is why?

```
let menuButton = UIButton()
let statusLabel = UILabel()
let segmentedLabel = UISegmentedControl(items: ["None", "Glow", "Cloud"])
func initializeUI() {
    //The menu button that opens up the options for the simulations
    menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    menuButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    menuButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    menuButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    menuButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburger.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
    view.addSubview(menuButton)

    //Will display the status of the simulation
    statusLabel.text = "Particle Simulation"
    statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    view.addSubview(statusLabel)

    //Will display visual options
    view.addSubview(segmentedLabel)
}
```

The size of each of the elements is perfect and they dont overlap. The label is in the bottom left corner the button is in the bottom right and the segmented view is in the top left corner (of my landscape app).

An additional question I have is if I wanted to start placing these objects programmatically how would I do so? The elements don't have an attribute position that I can work with and if I do something like  `menuButton.frame.size.height *= 20` that does not make the menu button super tall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I made I mistake thinking that this was UIKit behavior. There was code written that produces this effect that I did not see.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works is that all of your UI items in your example have an “intrinsic” content size so they are able to create their own frame. Add a standard UIView the same way and you will be out of luck. Also the views are creating their own constraints based on initial frames using Auto Resizing Masks(Also known as Springs and Struts).

Finally to place items you would set the frame directly. Just math. Good luck.

Super important to understand intrinsic content size. Some frame changes might require you to turn off automatic constraints but this is usually not the case but could be the problem with your button

```
   UIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: I can do the math for where the item needs to be but what property do I use to edit its position and size? I cant find the property that will allow you to edit it.

Comment: I have edited the transform and center attributes of the UIButton however they aren't changing things even if I call set needs display and do the transforms after adding it as a subview.